# AJAX requests to Node.JS to update JSON file for Jquery-comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

Jeez... How about that title, terrible lol.

Well I am using jquery-comments by Viima. (http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/)

I'm trying to use ajax commands to a Node.JS script that will update a JSON file. All of which is local, no crossing domains or anything.

Here is my **Node.JS** script:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

fs.writeFile("/comments-data.json", "commentJSON", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});

}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Here is the **Ajax post**

```
                postComment: function(commentJSON, success, error) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
                            data: commentJSON,
                            success: function(comment) {
                                success(comment)
                            },
                            error: error
                        });
                },
```

I don't want to redirect. I just wanted to asynchronously show the new comment. Also this script will ultimately have to be able to handle video attachments as well and store the filepath inside the JSON file. But i believe, Jquery-comments just reads the file path from the JSON

Here is what the support site says for attachments

```
    uploadAttachments: function(commentArray, success, error) {
        var responses = 0;
        var successfulUploads = [];

        var serverResponded = function() {
            responses++;

            // Check if all requests have finished
            if(responses == commentArray.length) {

                // Case: all failed
                if(successfulUploads.length == 0) {
                    error();

                // Case: some succeeded
                } else {
                    success(successfulUploads)
                }
            }
        }

        $(commentArray).each(function(index, commentJSON) {

            // Create form data
            var formData = new FormData();
            $(Object.keys(commentJSON)).each(function(index, key) {
                var value = commentJSON[key];
                if(value) formData.append(key, value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/comments/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(commentJSON) {
                    successfulUploads.push(commentJSON);
                    serverResponded();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    serverResponded();
                },
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't return any `res` to the http request so the ajax will timed out each time. Also you don't take any parameter from `req` to the json file.

Comment: If i replace commentJson with req it still fails. How should i return res?

Comment: Can anyone else provide any insight?

Comment: Test the node code without the Ajax, just simple Post requests. (with postman or similar tool)